# nonemptycrossjoin not working as intended in pps

Tags: ssas, mdx, dashboard

I have 2 linked filters in PPS and there's connection formula between them:

```
   nonemptycrossjoin
    ( 
       [SAMPLECODE].[SAMPLECODE].members,
        { <<UniqueName>> }
    )
```

This `nonemptycrossjoin` supposedly should take out the SAMPLECODE-members from the filter that have no measures (ie. null values). `And this MDX works when i try it in SSMS.`

Any ideas why `it's not working in PPS` ?

Comment: It's not working = The filter values are showing the null values also

Comment: Have you compared the full statement, or just fragments of the statements between PPS and SSMS? The full statement introduces a lot of context, which is extremely important in MDX. In order to really help you, we would have to see the full MDX statement.

Comment: select [Measures].[ASD] on 0,

nonemptycrossjoin(
[DCode].[DCode].children),[SAMPLECODE].[SAMPLECODE].members )


on 1
from p




I believe the essence of that query is in the connection formula?

Answer (score 1):

If it is the exact same MDX statement that behaves different depending on the environment (SSMS vs PPS) on the same cube, then I only could imagine that connection parameters or some session settings would influence the result.

Nevertheless, `NonEmptyCrossJoin` is [deprecated since SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144797%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). Instead of using this function, you could use the `NON EMPTY` axis modifier and an ordinary cross join, abbreviated as `*` as follows:

```
select [Measures].[ASD] on 0,
       non empty
       [DCode].[DCode].children * [SAMPLECODE].[SAMPLECODE].members
       on 1
  from p
```

**EDIT**

As - according to your comment - you get an error message for the non empty, I tried it on Adventure Works in AS2008R2, and the following query works fine:

```
select [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0,
       non empty
       [Customer].[Country].children * [Customer].[Gender].members
       on 1
  from [Adventure Works]
```

So, I would assume you have an error in the translation between the above query and your real query. I will not be able to find that without seeing your original query!

Comment: cannot really use that code in PPS: "Parser: The syntax for 'non' is incorrect." says the server profiler...

Comment: Then, maybe you can use the `NonEmpty` function instead: That would be `NonEmpty([DCode].[DCode].children * [SAMPLECODE].[SAMPLECODE].members)`

Comment: Or, are you by any chance using a pre-2005 version of Analysis Services? Then I will not be of help for you, as I never worked with a version that old.